# Uncheck checkbox using javascript after JS onload

Tags: javascript, controller, actionfunction

I am pasting a complete code for anyone reference if they like to resolve it.(Just incase they want to know what i could be missing.)
 NOTE: CaseOwnerChanged__c = Checkbox field type

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('{!Case.Id}');
        window.document.onload= new function(){
        if(({!Case.AccountId == '0013000000bFnBwAAK'} && {!Case.Classification__c =='ASO'})&&           {!Case.CaseOwnerChanged__c}){
                alert("xyz");
            }
            RevertCheckBox('{!Case.OwnerId}');           
       }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="RevertCheckBox" action="{!checkCaseOwner}"> 
            <apex:param id="anode" name="ownerIdVar" value="" assignTo="{!aCaseId}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am using a check box field a Case Object to check some condition, if its TRUE i am showing a popup (alert!!). But Once the checkbox is used to show the popup, i want to revert it back to false, for which i tried using RevertCheck JS function using ActionFunction, passing the Case.Id to controller, as

```
public with sharing class ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr {
    public static Id aCaseId {get;set;}

    public ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    public void checkCaseOwner(){
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+ aCaseId);
        Case c =[SELECT id,CaseOwnerChanged__c from case where id =: aCaseId];
        //Case c = new Case(Id = aCaseId);
        c.CaseOwnerChanged__c=false;
        update c;
    }
  }
```

But this does not works. Could you please help me this regard.!
Would be grateful. 
(If you want any  other details, please revert me back thru the same)
Thanks

Comment: Why you are creating a new `Case` object in the controller? you need to update a field of current case object isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's right,. So the reason i am passing on the ID to fetch same Case object I guess.

Comment: And on top I am not able to get  alert('<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>'); and system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+ aCaseId); in my log.

Comment: Where you call `RevertCheck()` JS function? without calling it you can't see `alert()` you can't see debug statement

Comment: I referred few similar questions, and as per the solutions, there is no need to call the RevertCheck() from an <apex:ActionFunction>. But I think required while using Remoting, we mention the funtion name to call it on the depending event... like onClick or...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Case standardController and controllerExtension, you no need of passing the case id to the controller. Just bind the Case record with the controller [as described in documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm).

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr {
    public Case c{get;set;}

    public ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.c = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public void checkCaseOwner(){
        c.CaseOwnerChanged__c=false;
        update c;
    }
  }
```

In the visualforce page you no need the `<apex:param />` since the loaded case record has been already bonded with the controller. 
VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="ChangeCaseOwnerNotificationCtrlr">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('{!Case.Id}');
        window.document.onload= new function(){
        if(({!Case.AccountId == '0013000000bFnBwAAK'} && {!Case.Classification__c =='ASO'})&&           {!Case.CaseOwnerChanged__c}){
                alert("xyz");
            }
            RevertCheckBox();           
       }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="RevertCheckBox" action="{!checkCaseOwner}"> 
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Note that you need a valid Case id in the URL to work this page properly since you are using standardController

Comment: Yes this did helped to query the right Case. But on research i found that, onlaod does not allows to call a method of a controller. In short it's due to Data Records and VF Pages in different servers combine to your UI, thus forbids the call.

Comment: Oh really?good one for research. But if i have not mistaken i have used onload to call the controller.may be it's with salesforce RPC